# Swift - All cells change when I add a new one (want individual cells)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a project and I need some help. I have my app connected to Firebase and it is coded in Swift.

**My problem:**

When I press the "Share" button does it send the coordinates to Firebase (longitude and latitude). A cell adds in my `UICollectionViewController` and retrieves the coordinates from Firebase. So it shows up on a map in the `UICollectionViewCell`. So far so good. But when I press the "Share" button again from another position it adds another cell again, but this time it change the position on all of the cells to the latest position.

Even if I'm logged in with another user it changes. I suspects that I have to put the `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` in

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 

indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Hope you guys can understand this. It´s little bit hard to do this thing good, pretty new in this thing.

PS: The code may not be the best, but I just want help with what I'm asking for...

**Here is my code**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlow

Layout {

    let cellId = "cellId"



var users = [User]()

var positions = [Position]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))

    navigationItem.title = "Profile"

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView?.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    observePosition()




    }

    func handleLogout() {

        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
        } catch let logoutError {
            print(logoutError)
        }

        let loginContoller = LoginController()
        present(loginContoller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    func observePosition() {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("position")
        ref.observe(.child

Added, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let position = Position()
            position.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.positions.append(position)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView!.reloadData()
            })

    }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return positions.count
}



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 

indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let FedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        let position = positions[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


        if let fromId = position.fromId { //To get the username 
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(fromId) //get username
            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    FedCell.nameLabel.text = dictionary["name"] as? String //get username 


                }


            }, withCancel: nil)

        }


        return FedCell


}




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 450)
    }
```

**And my cell**

```
class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {



    var user = [User]()

    var positions = [Position]()


 private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        if let mapView = self.mapView {
             let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, self.distanceSpan, self.distanceSpan)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("position")
        ref.obse

rve(.childAdded, with: { (locationSnap) in





        if let locationDict = locationSnap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {



            guard let lat = locationDict["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees,
                let long = locationDict["longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees else { return }



            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

            let locationPin = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = locationPin


            self.mapView!.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            self.mapView!.showsUserLocation = false
            self.mapView!.addAnnotation(annotation)
            self.mapView!.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()



        }

    })


   }


}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line: `let position = positions[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]`.  What's inside your `positions`?  Is it the data you expect?  Is it several different locations?

Comment: What's positions.fromId? does that change?

Comment: I get 8 values inside position, I have 8 different values/positions in Firebase Storage. And it finds "longitude" and "latitude" as NSNumber. Just to point out that the code  in 'cellForItemAt indexPath' is just to get the username that posted the "cell" and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of re-usability of cells. 
You will need to set location in the same method where you are setting name by keeping in mind that they should not override with a new value.

Comment: Okay, now I have set the location inside the same method where I set the name. It still doing the same thing but I think they override with a new value (?) How do I fix so it don´t override with a new value? Sorry but I'm pretty new in Swift so I need help. Have googled around a little but can't gain an understanding.

Comment: It would be better to create a model class to store the data which need to show on cells. And populate your cells from the model class which will not let override the old values.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that I don´t understand how I´m going to do that. As I said, I´m pretty new in Swift...

Comment: Create a Model class (May be of type NSObject).

Declare properties which you want to store in this model like location, name etc.

Assign values to this model class in your controller and keep adding them into an array to populate your tableview.

Now, in cellforrowatIndexPath method, access this model class from array you created and set values in your cell.

That's it..!!